# PHP rand function generates duplicated hash occasionally

Tags: php, random

I have a system running on Ubuntu + Nginx + PHP5.3 + APC.

I have a function to generate a hash string used as UID to identify an entity

```
function rand_hex($length = 24)
{
    $select = '0123456789abcdef';
    $ret = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
        $ret .= $select[rand(0,strlen($select)-1)];

    return $ret;

}
```

Recently I started experiencing intermittent issues where multiple Entities shared the same UID generated. This happens 1 in about 50 times and when it happens, two entities are created within the same 1 hour window, and most of them happened within the same 5 second window. The two entities that shared the same UID can sometimes be created by different users (i.e. different accounts and different browsers )

It looks like the rand_hex function is kinda cached and generate same result. I've already search through the application for application logic error without success. I wonder if anyone has any clue . Thanks in advance.

**NOTE**: I know the code itself is not good and there are many better ways to generate UIDs. I am working with a legacy system.

Comment: 1. It's not a hash. 2. Try to use `mt_rand` instead of `rand`.

Comment: Yes, I know, using mt_rand was my first try. But I still could not explain what's going on.

Comment: Are your sure that you are not calling `srand` function with const value?

Comment: Thanks, no, it is just rand(), the evil function

Comment: check project for `srand` (`mt_srand`) calling